# preg_replace text highlight to ignore URLs

Tags: php, preg-replace

i am using preg_replace for highlighting words in search results. search result sometimes  also contains URL, not just text. and some URLs contain key words. then URLs get messed up as preg_replace also changes the URL.

is there any way to ignore URLs in preg_replace?

this is what i use:

`$result = preg_replace('!('.$keyword.')!i', '<span style="background: #f00;">$1</span>', $result);`

thank you!

Comment: Something like `"!\\b($keyword)\\b!i"`, perhaps? Or is it intended to `span` keywords if they're parts of bigger words? )

Answer (score 1):

Edited..
okay, than is this helpful?
Make your result as array and then check if it contains url?

```
 <?php
    $result = "This is Stpartāāa http://google.lv ";
    $arr = explode(" ", $result);
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ((strpos($value,'http://') !== false) AND (strpos($value,'www.') !== false)) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                // do somthing
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: 1) it's $result that may contain URLs, not $keyword; 2) URLs that do not contain 'www' are not so rare, no need to check for them; 3) what about https?

Comment: @moonwave99 Nah, who uses it these days. )